# Is there a way to console.log an array using a function containing a for loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, return, console.log

I'd like to print an array using a function that contains a simple **for loop**. So far my code will only list the first item in the array. It seems the **return** value only allows for the function to run once. But how do I get the code to continue iterating over the loop until the ending condition is met?

```
function aureliaStuff() {
    let aureliaInventory = ["Red Leather Duster Jacket", " 10mm 
    Pistol", " Black Sunglasses", " A Harley Davidson Motorbike", " A 
    Pack of Camel Cigarettes", " A Sister of Mercy CD", " The Lost 
    Boys On VHS."];

        for (let i = 0; i < aureliaInventory.length; i++) {
            let item = aureliaInventory[i]

            return item;
        };
}

console.log(aureliaStuff());
```

It just prints the first item in the array, **"Red Leather Duster Jacket"** and nothing else.

Why can't I seem to log the full array when I return a variable from my loop?

Comment: The console.log needs to be in a loop

Comment: @DanielA.White Do you mean this particular for loop? Or its own loop? I tried changing to:
```
for (let i = 0; i < aureliaInventory.length; i++) {
       let item = aureliaInventory[i]

       console.log(item);
  };
```
but it prints **undefined** after the array list. When I try to return a value to take remove **undefined**, it does what it was doing before. Just returns the first item of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function aureliaStuff()
{
    let aureliaInventory = ["Red Leather Duster Jacket", " 10mm
                            Pistol", " Black Sunglasses", " A Harley 
                            Davidson Motorbike", " A
                            Pack of Camel Cigarettes", " A Sister of Mercy 
                            CD", " The Lost Boys On VHS."];
for (let i = 0; i < aureliaInventory.length; i++) 
  {
    console.log(aureliaInventory[i]);
  }
}

aureliaStuff();
```